# 2005 Chevy Classic (malibu) with loose timing chain/broken guide?

Tags: chevrolet, timing, chain, timing-chain, malibu-classic

Heard a knocking noise I feared was rodknock. Took it to the mechanic and they spent an hour looking at it and said the timing chain is loose and the guide is broken and separated from the bracket.

Quoted me around $1,000~. $600 parts. $500 labor. Not guaranteed this is the cause of the sound.

Car itself is only valued around $2k.

Is it worth it? I don't really have money for a new car, but there's no guarantee this one won't continue to have more issues after this fix either.

Is $1k reasonable?

Is it something I, with no garage and limited mechanical experience, could replace myself?

Should I call back and ask them to check the oil/filter for metal shavings to try to further rule out a messed up rod/bearing in the engine?

Comment: There's no guarantee a "new" one won't have issues either...

Comment: $600 for parts sound like a lot, so I'd find out what all they want to replace.  They might also be doing the water pump or similar on a job that size because its easy to get to at the same time (for example, never worked on that car).  So, get details of what all they want to do, then get a second estimate.

Comment: Everywhere I called around estimated me about that price as well. Apparently the parts are a kit for replacement.

Comment: which engine do you have? the 3.8? as long as you follow service information chains aren’t that tough, just time consuming. if you’ve never done one before be prepared for extended downtime.

Comment: 2.2L. I don't have a garage or tools and I'd be paying about $40/day to get to/from work in addition to however much to go buy tools/parts. Just went ahead and told them to do it for the 1k. I'll be able to drive to work tomorrow.

Comment: Good old ecotec. I see a lot of broken chain guides/stretched chains from lack of maintenance. It's actually super easy to do on those provided you have the tools etc...